# How to use a int in a different class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
//class1

competitionSettingsViewController.m

int *myint;

// in some void I made.
myint = 7;

//class2
competitionViewcontroller.m

#import "competitionSettingsViewController.m" 

int *myextraint = 0;

competitionSettingsViewController a = [[competitionSettingsViewController alloc]........]
myextraint = a.myint;
```

Comment: If you have a helpful answer you should accept it. Click on checkmark under upvote/downvote counter. This will mark the question as "answered" and provide you with small reputation bonus. See [How do I ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) FAQ article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) as follows:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property int myInt;
@end
```

You can then access it as follows:

```
MyObject mo        = [[MyObject alloc] init];
int myExtraInt     = mo.myInt; 
int myAltExtraInt  = [mo myInt];
```

Comment: Wow always by the time I write my answer someone beats me to it, this looks like a race to knowledge sharing. Good answer though.

Comment: But should I import the .h or .m file then?

Comment: @harry: Furthermore the interface block should be in the header file.  Once imported into a .m you can use it as shown in the second code block.

Comment: Ok ty verry much I am a bit new to Objective C.